# C#, Display plain text in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, plaintext

I can only find rather "complex" functions, like RTF Text box etc. I couldn't figure out how to display "plain text" in a Form1.cs

(I do not talk about HTML to WinForm. Search did not return any useful results)

Comment: your code didn't compile

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-create-a-read-only-text-box-windows-forms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a Label or a TextBox.

If you use a TextBox, set MultiLine to true and ReadOnly to true to not allow editing.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `TextBox` or `Label`.  That's what they're designed for - displaying plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Label is not very suitable for that. It makes a new line only on "\r\n", which means a very long paragraph may exceed size of the form.

A TextBox with the following properties is perfect for it:

1. Multiple lines
2. ReadOnly = true
3. No border.

And, drag the right / bottom borders to align with borders of the form, it's size will automatically change along with the form.